# What is the intersection of inductive definable subsets of a real closed field?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, real-numbers, model-theory, peano-axioms

Let $X$ be a real closed field.  Let us call a subset of $X$ definable if it is definable using a first-order formula in the language of ordered fields without parameters from $X$.  And let us call a subset of $X$ inductive if it contains $0$ and if it contains $x$, then it contains $x+1$.  And let $M$ be the intersection of all definable inductive subsets of $X$.

Then my question is, what are the properties of $M$, as a model for the language for first-order arithmetic?  I don’t think $M$ is necessarily isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, but clearly it satisfies the axioms of Robinson arithmetic at least.  But how strong a form of induction must it satisfy?

Comment: By a theorem of Mourgues and Ressayre, every real-closed field has an integer part (which is the title of the corresponding paper). Integer parts are models of Open Induction, i.e. of Robinson arithmetic + induction scheme for quantifier-free formulas. Their proof relies on the axiom of choice in a way that I don't think can be circumvented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\varphi(x)$ is a formula and $M$ is a model, I will write $\varphi(M)$ for the subset of $M$ defined by $\varphi(x)$.

In any real closed field $R$, a formula with one free variable (even with parameters from $R$) defines a finite union of points of $R$ and intervals with endpoints in $R$ or $\pm \infty$ (this is called o-minimality). If $\varphi(x)$ is such a formula *without parameters*, then we can interpret this formula in $\mathbb{Q}^r$, the field of real algebraic numbers (this is the real closure of $\mathbb{Q}$, and the prime model of the theory of real closed fields). Since $R$ is an elementary extension of $\mathbb{Q}^r$, it follows that $\varphi(R)$ is a finite union of points in $\mathbb{Q}^r$ and intervals with endpoints in $\mathbb{Q}^r$ or $\pm \infty$.

[For example, if $\varphi(\mathbb{Q}^r) = \{0\}\cup (\sqrt{2},\infty)$, then $\mathbb{Q}^r\models \forall x(\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow (x = 0\lor \sqrt{2}<x))$, so also $R\models \forall x(\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow (x = 0\lor \sqrt{2}<x))$, and hence $\varphi(R) = \{0\}\cup (\sqrt{2},\infty)$.]

Now if $\varphi(R)$ is inductive, then $\varphi(\mathbb{Q}^r)$ is unbounded above in $\mathbb{Q}^r$. Thus there is a real algebraic number $a$ such that $\varphi(\mathbb{Q}^r)$ contains $(a,\infty)$, and hence $\varphi(R)$ also contains $(a,\infty)$. In particular, $\varphi(R)$ contains $\mathbb{N}\cup \{x\in R\mid x > \mathbb{N}\}$.

It remains to show that the intersection of all inductive definable sets (without parameters) in $R$ is exactly $\mathbb{N}\cup \{x\in R\mid x > \mathbb{N}\}$. This is just as in nombre's answer: For each natural number $n$, the set $S_n = \{0,1,\dots,n\}\cup (n,\infty)$ is definable, and $\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} S_n = \mathbb{N}\cup \{x\in R\mid x > \mathbb{N}\}$.

Note that if $R$ is Archimedean, then $\mathbb{N}\cup \{x\in R\mid x > \mathbb{N}\} = \mathbb{N}$. But if $R$ is non-Archimedean, this set is much larger, and it doesn't look much like a model of arithemetic. In particular, the infinite elements are densely ordered. (Though my earlier comment was wrong: it seems it does satisfy the axioms of Robinson artithmetic. I forgot how weak the axioms of Q are.)

---

**Regarding induction:** If $R$ is Archimedean, then $M = \mathbb{N}$ so of course it satisfies full (second-order) induction.

If $R$ is non-Archimedean, then $M$ fails induction already for the formula $\psi(x)$ which says "$x$ is odd or $x+1$ is odd": $$\forall y\,\forall z\, (y+y \neq x) \lor  (z+z\neq x+1).$$

This formula is false for all infinite elements of $M$, but it is true for all finite elements, so it defines $\mathbb{N}$ in $M$. Really, you should think of $M$ as looking like a definable copy of $\mathbb{N}$ with a bunch of extraneous densely-ordered junk on top. If you're trying to find a reasonable model of arithmetic inside a real closed field, I think nombre's comment above about integer parts is much more relevant than this construction.

---

**Quantifier-free induction:** In the comments, you asked whether $M$ satisfies induction for quantifier-free formulas. The answer is yes, but this is a bit silly, since quantifier-free formulas just define finite unions of points and intervals.

Suppose $\varphi(x)$ is a quantifier-free formula. Let's allow $\varphi$ to have parameters and include the symbol $\leq$. Since $\varphi$ is quantifier-free, $\varphi(M) = \varphi(R)\cap M$. Suppose $\varphi(M)$ is inductive. Then it contains $\mathbb{N}$, so we can focus on the infinite elements of $\varphi(M)$, which are exactly the infinite elements of $\varphi(R)$. Suppose for contradiction that $\varphi(M)\neq M$. Since $\varphi(R)$ is a finite union of points and intervals with endpoints in $R$ or $\pm \infty$, and $\varphi(R)$ is unbounded in $\mathbb{N}$, there is some infinite $a\in R$ such that $(-\infty,a)\cap \{x\in R\mid x > \mathbb{N}\}$ is contained in $\varphi(R)$, but there exists $\varepsilon$ such that $0<\varepsilon < 1$, and $a+\varepsilon\notin \varphi(R)$. Then $a+\varepsilon - 1\in \varphi(R)$, contradicting inductiveness.

Comment: OK, so my question remains, how much induction does M satisfy?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Does the language of first-order arithmetic include $<$?

Comment: No, it doesn’t.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I've edited with a comment on induction.

Comment: Well, the weakest form of induction is induction on quantifier-free formulas.  Does M satisfy that?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I don't know, and I'm afraid I don't have any more time to think about this. Good luck!

Comment: No problem, thanks for your efforts!  Maybe a bounty will produce more answers.

Comment: The formula given by Alex Kruckman is a consequence of the induction scheme for the corresponding quantifier-free formula. By a theorem of Shepherdson, models of Open Induction are exactly integer parts of real-closed fields.

Comment: @nombre How would you prove the formula given by Alex using quantifier-free induction?

Comment: Fix $a,b \in R$ assuming $R$ satisfies Open Induction. Apply the induction scheme to the formula where $y$ and $z$ are replaced by $a$ and $b$ and the quantifiers are discarded.

Comment: @nombre No, that won’t work.  Our language does not have names for all the elements of $R$, only some of them.  So it is not true that for all $a,b\in R$ there exists a formula that expresses that either $a+a\neq x$ or $b+b\neq x + 1$.  So that doesn’t demonstrate that $M$ fails to satisfy quantifier free induction.

Comment: @nombre Isn't the theorem actually that *discretely ordered* models of open induction are exactly integer parts of real-closed fields? I now think that Keshav is right that this structure $M = \mathbb{N}\cup \{x\in R\mid x > \mathbb{N}\}$ satisfies open induction (in a rather trivial way) despite not being discretely ordered. See my edit.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan : Actually I meant $a,b \in M$. But you're right, the formula is not inductive (in $M$) in general so it does not give a counter example.

Comment: @AlexKruckman You're right! My bad.

Comment: OK, so it satisfies quantifier-free induction but not bounded induction right?  (Bounded induction being induction on formulas with bounded quantifiers like for all x less than y and there exists an x less than y.)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan That's right. I don't know how you intend to express bounded induction when you don't have $\leq$ in the language, though...

Comment: Yeah, for bounded arithmetic you need to add $\leq$ to the language.  Anyway thanks for all your help!  And your help too @nombre

Comment: I just posted a follow-up question: ‪https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3767375/71829‬

Answer (score 0):

The intersection is actually isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$.

Indeed, for $x > \mathbb{N}$ in $X$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, consider the set $S_{x,n}:=\{0,1,..,n-1\} \cup [n,x)$. This set is semialgebraic and inductive. The intersection of all $S_{x,n}$ is $\mathbb{N}$, so your intersection is $\mathbb{N}$.

As a general rule, it is not so easy to find non-standard models of large segments of $Th(\mathbb{N})$ in a given ordered field, especially in a canonical way.

Comment: But $x$ is not in the language, is it?  I’m only interested in sets which are definable by first-order formulas in the language of ordered fields.  And that language doesn’t have names for all the elements of $X$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Can you post an answer with these points?  And can you also address, even if $M$ doesn’t satisfy Robinson arithmetic, how much of induction does it satisfy?