# Where is the copy of $\mathbb{N}$ in the constructible hierarchy relative to a real closed field?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, set-theory, real-numbers

Let $X$ be a real closed field.  Let us define a constructible hierarchy relative to $X$ is defined as follows.  (This is slightly nonstandard terminology.). Let $L_0(X)=X$.  For any ordinal $\beta$, let $L_{\beta+1}(X)=Def(L_{\beta+1}(X))$.  For any limit ordinal $\gamma$, let $L_\gamma(X)=\cup_{\beta<\gamma}L_\beta$.  And finally let $L(X) = \cup_\alpha L_\alpha$.

Now let $M=\{n1_X: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  Then my question is, what is the smallest ordinal $\alpha$ such that $M$ is guaranteed to be an element of $L_{\alpha}(X)$?

Or is it consistent that $M\notin L(X)$?  What if we were to add the axiom $V=L(X)$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I just copied Wikipedia’s definition of relative constructability.  It didn’t make sense to me why you’d take the transitive closure of the set rather than just starting with the set itself, and after seeing your comment it seems to me like Wikipedia’s definition trivializes my question.  So I’m going to go back to my first instinct and use a nonstandard definition of relative constructability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid notational clash, I'll use the notation $D_\alpha(X)$ to describe the hierarchy built on an RCF $X=(A;f_1,f_2)$ with underlying set $A$, addition function $f_1$, and multiplication function $f_2$, defined  precisely as follows:

- At the successor and limit steps we take definable powersets and unions respectively, as usual.
- We start with $D_0(X)=A\cup A^2\cup\{f_1,f_2\}$.

Here are a couple quick comments to demonstrate that $D_0(X)$ really does have at least the "bare minimum" of expressive power we want for a set-theoretic implementation of an RCF:

- We have $f_1, f_2\subseteq D_0(X)$ (and consequently $f_1,f_2$ are definable subsets of $D_0(X)$ since also $f_1,f_2\in D_0(X)$). This is because $A^2\subseteq D_0(X)$ and $f_1,f_2\subseteq A^2$.
- We have that $A$ is a definable subset of $D_0(X)$ -  e.g. as "The set of left coordinates of elements of $f_1$."
- We can tell which of $f_1$ and $f_2$ is addition and which is multiplication, by asking which has an annihilator.

---

Now right away, we can make the following observation.  As we go along the $D$-hierarchy, we "accidentally" wind up following the usual construction of $L$. In particular, we have $A^{<\omega}\subseteq D_\omega(X)$. This lets us implement the "natural" definition of $M$ in $D_{\omega+1}(X)$: "$M$ is the set of $m\in A$ such that there is some finite sequence of elements of $A$ whose first term is $1_X$, whose last term is $m$, and whose $(i+1)$th term is the $i$th term $+_X1_X$." This gives us the following:

> $\alpha\le\omega+1.$

Can we do better? Well, at least for some presentations we can easily. Specifically, suppose that $$\mathcal{P}(A)\cap D_1(X)=Def(X),$$ where $Def(X)$ is the set of subsets of $A$ which are definable in the RCF $X$ in the model-theoretic sense. Then by o-minimality of RCF, we have that the following are equivalent for $U\in \mathcal{P}(A)\cap D_1(X)=Def(X)$:

- $U$ is discrete, has $1_X$ as its least element, and for each $d\in U$ with $d\not=1_X$ we have $d-_X1_X\in U$.
- $U=\{1\cdot 1_X, 2\cdot 1_X, ..., n\cdot 1_X\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}$.

This gives us $M\in D_2(X)$: we have $m\in M$ iff there is some $U\in \mathcal{P}(A)\cap D_1(X)=Def(X)$ satisfying the above two bulletpoints with $m\in U$. Consequently, we have:

> Restricted to "model-theoretically efficient" presentations of RCFs, that is, ones where $D_1(X)$ is "minimal," we have $\alpha=2$.

(It's easy to show $\alpha>1$.)

Moreover, we can get this unconditionally if $X$ is additionally Archimedean. This is because we can simply add the criterion that $U$ be bounded above and below; the only subsets of $A$ which are bounded above and below, contain $1_X$, and are closed under subtracting $1_X$ from ever non-$1_X$ element are the sets of the form $\{1\cdot 1_X, 2\cdot 1_X, ..., n\cdot 1_X\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. That is:

> If $X$ is Archimedean, then $\alpha=2$.

However, we run into a problem if $X$ is non-Archimedean *and* is presented in such a way that non-definable-in-$X$ subsets of $A$ show up in $D_1(X)$. In general I don't see a way to improve on the $\omega+1$ bound.

> **Conjecture**: There is an RCF $X$ whose $\alpha$ is exactly $\omega+1$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t notice that you posted an answer while I was editing my question.  I just changed my definition of relative constructability to start with X rather than a transitive closure.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Well, now it **really** matters how you present $X$. E.g. presumably you want each of the elements of the underlying set of the RCF to be in $L_0(X)$, right? Letting $X=(A; f_1,f_2)$, I think the right approach is probably $$L_0(X)=A\cup A^2\cup\{f_1,f_2\}$$ (note that we can tell which of $f_1$ and $f_2$ is addition/multiplication by looking at which one has an annihilator).

Comment: Yes, I do.  And I also want the formulas that the definable powerset operation is allowed to use to be able to use the symbols +, *, and <.  I just don’t know what the best way to formalize that is.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think the approach from my previous comment is basically ideal - it's the "bare-bones" approach (keep in mind that the ordering is definable from the addition and multiplication, so we'll get it soon), which will have the effect of making $\alpha$ as big as possible. Since we have an upper bound on $\alpha$ already, that's a good idea in my opinion.

Comment: OK, let’s go with that.

Comment: How does your argument for $\alpha\le\omega+1$ go through with my modified definition of relative constructability?  Aren’t we no longer allowed to make reference to natural numbers in defining definable subsets?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan The point is that by level $\omega$ we've *built* the natural numbers, so we do get to use them at the next level. (Regardless of $X$ we have $\emptyset\in L_1(X)$, $\{\emptyset\}\in L_2(X)$, $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\in L_3(X)$, etc.)

Comment: You mean we’ve built them in the von Neumann definition?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, exactly (see the parenthetical remark in my previous comment).

Comment: What happened to the $\alpha=3$ thing, did it not work out?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan See my edit. I think I've got it this time.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question, since I was definitely aiming for $\mathcal{P}(A)\cap D_1(X)=Def(X)$.

Comment: This may be obvious, but why does $U$ need to be discrete?  If $U$ is closed under subtracting 1 and it has 1 as its least element, why is that not enough to conclude that it’s of the form $\{1_X, 2 1_X, ..., n 1_X\}$?

Comment: I’m pretty sure such a set can’t have any nondegenerate intervals or infinite elements.

Comment: I just posted a follow-up question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/3781504/71829