# Where is the first gap in the constructible hierarchy relative to a real closed field?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, set-theory, real-numbers

This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3767375/71829).  Let $X= (A,+,*)$ be a real closed field.  Let us define a constructible hierarchy relative to $X$ as follows.  Let $D_0(X)=A\cup A^2 \cup \{+,*\}$.  For any ordinal $\beta$, let $D_{\beta+1}(X)=Def(D_{\beta+1}(X))$.  For any limit ordinal $\gamma$, let $D_\gamma(X)=\cup_{\beta<\gamma}D_\beta$.

Then my question is, what is the least ordinal $\lambda$ such that it’s guaranteed that $P(A)\cap D_\alpha(X) = P(A)\cap D_{\alpha+1}(X)$ for some $\alpha\leq\lambda$?  Note that this is related to the notion of Gaps in the Constructible Universe.