# How high in the constructible hierarchy do you need to go to see Dedekind-incompleteness?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, set-theory, real-numbers, model-theory

This is a follow-up to my questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3767375/71829) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3781504/71829).  Let $X= (A,+,*,<)$ be an ordered field.  Let us define a constructible hierarchy relative to $X$ as follows.  Let $D_0(X)=A\cup A^2 \cup \{+,*,<\}$.  For any ordinal $\beta$, let $D_{\beta+1}(X)=Def(D_{\beta+1}(X))$.  For any limit ordinal $\gamma$, let $D_\gamma(X)=\cup_{\beta<\gamma}D_\beta$.  Finally, let $D(X)=\cup_\alpha D_\alpha$.

Suppose that $D(X)=V$, and that $X$ is not Dedekind-complete. Then my question is, what is the least $\alpha$ such that $D_\alpha(X)$ sees that $X$ is not Dedekind-complete, that is, such that $D_\alpha(X)$ contains a nonempty bounded-above subset of $X$ with no least upper bound in $X$?

Comment: I think this question would be more clearly phrased as: $$$$ **Suppose $D(X)=V$ and $X$ is not complete. What is the least $\alpha$ such that $D_\alpha(X)$ sees that $X$ is not complete, that is, such that $D_\alpha(X)$ contains a nonempty bounded-above subset of $X$ with no least upper bound in $X$?** $$$$ 
As written it's somewhat turned around. On that note, the assumption of $D(X)=V$ is basically necessary. Certainly *some* assumption is necessary (consider $\mathbb{R}^L$ under the assumption that $\mathbb{R}^L\subsetneq V$ and note that $D(\mathbb{R}^L)=L$). (cont'd)

Comment: And while "$D(X)=V$" is overkill, it's benign overkill: as long as $D(X)$ sees that $X$ is incomplete, $D(X)$ and $V$ will agree on *when* in the $D(X)$-hierarchy this occurs since everything is nicely absolute. So I think that's the right phrasing for this question. (Incidentally, I just upvoted - the downvote seems silly to me.)

Comment: Also I don't really see what the title has to do with the body: the title question is immediately answered by considering $\mathbb{R}^L$ under the assumption $\mathbb{R}^L\not=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK, I rephrased the question and changed the title.